# What could be causing lines on my VGA output?

Tags: graphics-card, vga, nvidia-geforce

I have a Power Mac G4 with an nVidia Geforce2 MX graphics card. It has two outputs: an ADC output (DVI + power + USB) and a VGA output. The ADC connection works fine, but over VGA the screen is much darker with brighter lines going across the screen. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNXdF.jpg) is what the outputs look like. What could be causing this issue? And would it be possible to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried a different cable? This looks like a shielding problem. But is also characteristic of defective capacitors which cause filtering problems. Most likely it’s simply old, defective hardware.

Comment: I've used multiple cables and monitors, and the problem is still there. The card only has two electrolytic capacitors, though I don't have any way to test them.

Comment: Do the caps look bulged or anything? The tops should be flat. Somewhere the analog signal is bleeding together.

Comment: Nope, they look completely normal. (Note these capacitors are metal all around.)